# Post empty body with Jersey 2 client

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

How do I submit a post request with an empty body with a Jersey 2 client?

```
final MyClass result = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("http://localhost:8080")
    .path("path")
    .queryParam("key", "value")
    .request(APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(What to fill in here if the body should be left empty??, MyClass.class);
```

---

**Update:** this works:

```
final MyClass result = ClientBuilder
    .newBuilder().register(JacksonFeature).build()
    .target("http://localhost:8080")
    .path("path")
    .queryParam("key", "value")
    .request(APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(null, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: I'm late to the party, but FWIW your update is the answer to my particular problem - specifically I don't want a Content-Type header :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can't find this in the doc's anywhere, but I believe you can use `null` to get an empty body:

```
final MyClass result = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("http://localhost:8080")
    .path("path")
    .queryParam("key", "value")
    .request(APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.json(null), MyClass.class)
```

Comment: I tried that but got a `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,...`?

Comment: Well that's an entirely different problem... you should either register the default JacksonFeature, or write your own MessageBodyWriter/Reader

Comment: Ah I see you wrote that above, sorry. So `null` is the correct answer, right?

Comment: Thats stupid. Should be an Enity.empty() static method

Comment: The problem with this approach is that jersey will still set the content-type header according to the Entity-factory (in this case `application/json`).

Comment: This works but I believe it does not send a 'Content-Length: 0' header... some endpoints apparently require a Content-Length if you send a POST. Is there a way to add a header manually?

Comment: You can add headers between the request and post calls if you need to: `.request(APPLICATION_JSON).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, 0).post(Entity.json(null), MyClass.class)`

Comment: As @Hank points out this will make a request with the `Content-Type` set to `application/json` which might not be what you want. If you want to POST an empty form, try `post(Entity.form(new Form()))`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Entity.json("") works fine.

Answer (score 12):

I found that this worked for me:

```
Response r = client
    .target(url)
    .path(path)
    .queryParam(name, value)
    .request()
    .put(Entity.json(""));
```

Pass an empty string, not a null value.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if the version change it. But, the following doesn't work:

`builder.put( Entity.json( null )  );`

Where, the following works fine:

`builder.put( Entity.json( "" )  );`

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying to unit test where the parameter value comes through as `null`. I tried the `Entity.json("{}")` answer suggested but that gave me a parameter with an instance with every field `null` rather than the parameter which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Just post an empty txt.

```
   .post(Entity.text(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me only with an empty json object string

```
.post(Entity.json("{}")
```

All other solutions, still produced `400 Bad Request`

P.S. The request is done using `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`